# Shopify-Bridge Call to undefined function getShopifyConfig()

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I am trying to setup the appbridge for my shopify APP

I am using this logic here:

```
@if(\Osiset\ShopifyApp\getShopifyConfig('appbridge_enabled'))
      <script>
          src="https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge{{ \Osiset\ShopifyApp\getShopifyConfig('appbridge_version') ? '@'.config('shopify-app.appbridge_version') : '' }}"></script>
      <script>
          var AppBridge = window['app-bridge'];
          var createApp = AppBridge.default;
          var app = createApp({
              apiKey: '{{ \Osiset\ShopifyApp\getShopifyConfig('api_key') }}',
              shopOrigin: '{{ Auth::user()->name }}',
              forceRedirect: true,
          });
      </script>

      @include('shopify-app::partials.flash_messages')
  @endif
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error
Call to undefined function Osiset\ShopifyApp\getShopifyConfig() (View:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no helper `getShopifyConfig()`. I think it's a typo, and need to correct it:

```
@if(\Osiset\ShopifyApp\Util::getShopifyConfig('appbridge_enabled'))
  <script>
      src="https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge{{ \Osiset\ShopifyApp\Util::getShopifyConfig('appbridge_version') ? '@'.config('shopify-app.appbridge_version') : '' }}"></script>
  <script>
      var AppBridge = window['app-bridge'];
      var createApp = AppBridge.default;
      var app = createApp({
          apiKey: '{{ \Osiset\ShopifyApp\Util::getShopifyConfig('api_key') }}',
          shopOrigin: '{{ Auth::user()->name }}',
          forceRedirect: true,
      });
  </script>

  @include('shopify-app::partials.flash_messages')
@endif
```